# Does DPDK provide an interface to forward packets from one process to another?

Tags: dpdk

Does DPDK provide an interface to forward packets from one process to another? Similar to the loopback mode of the kernel, but faster than the loopback mode.

Comment: What have you already tried or read? Please provide any relevant code and error messages.

Comment: In my scenario, dpdk is required for primary/secondary process communication and secondary/secondary process communication. I want to know whether the dpdk provides related interfaces.